# Apex equivalent of PHP sha1() and some more encoding methods

Tags: apex, php, hashcode, url-encode

I got a PHP script to generate an encoded URL.
I need to translate this script into Apex code to generate the same URL. However, the PHP encode functions seem to work differently from Apex.

The relevant PHP encoding functions are:

1. hash("MD5", microtime())
2. $key = sha1(sha1($var1 . $var2) . $var2);
3. bin2hex($var1)

The code I used to generate them in Apex:

1. `String microTimeTemp = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime());
   Blob microtime = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(microTimeTemp);
   Blob hashMicrotime = Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', microtime);
   hashTime = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hashMicrotime);`

The closest thing I can think of to PHP microtime() is `DateTime.now().getTime().` However, it seems they return different values:

> in PHP microtime(): 0.85386700 1457657994
>
> in Apex DateTime.now().getTime(): 1457658064186

Salesforce explained that the DateTime.now().getTime() returns the value of the time count since 1970.

2. This one is the most complicated one. I actually made meaningful variables. Here I just use 1,2,3,4 for not giving real names:

`String var1 = 'The String value 1';
String var2 = 'The String value 2';`

`String var3 = var1 + var2;
Blob blob1 = Blob.valueOf(var3);
Blob hash1 = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', blob1);`

`String var4 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hash1) + var2;
Blob blob2 = Blob.valueOf(var4);
Blob hash2 = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', blob2);
String key = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hash2);`

3. I think this one might generate the same thing as PHP code? I am not sure:

`String hex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Blob.valueOf(var1));`

When I combined them together, I am pretty sure it was not the same URL generated by the PHP script. Is there a way for Apex to generate the same URL as PHP?
Also need to do something encoding as "ASCII"?

Comment: All you do is generating unique random string. Whether it's milliseconds in PHP or APEX, why does it matter? The result will always be a unique random string. Also you can never compare the two and get the same value because X milliseconds have passed between executing one and another code.

Comment: Well. The milliseconds does not matter. How about the SHA1 method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it would look like in APEX:

```
String md5 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', Blob.valueOf(String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()))));
system.debug(md5);

String var1 = 'The String value 1'; 
String var2 = 'The String value 2';
String sha1 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', Blob.valueOf(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1', Blob.valueOf(var1 + var2))) + var2)));
system.debug(sha1);

String bin2hex = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(var1));
system.debug(bin2hex);
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got time to test your code. I used another way to sync the data. I will now give this answer the best answer. Later, I will have a test to see if this code works.